# Android - requestFocus not working in EditText

Tags: android

I'm facing a strange situation. Consider the next fragments of code:
(XML):

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+vistoria/CNPJTomador"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:maxLength="18"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Java:

```
CNPJTomador = (EditText) findViewById(R.vistoria.CNPJTomador);
CNPJTomador.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    if(!hasFocus && !Validation.isCNPJ(CNPJTomador.getText().toString())) {
        Toast.makeText(Checklist.this, "CNPJ inválido!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        CNPJTomador.requestFocus(); 
    }
    else if (!hasFocus && Validation.isCNPJ(CNPJTomador.getText().toString())) 
        CNPJTomador.setText(Validation.printCNPJ(CNPJTomador.getText().toString()));
    }
});
```

When the user go to another field, it should make the data validation and put back the focus in case of any error. However, at this point the system become crazy. It's impossible to recover the focus. If I click into another EditText, both get blinking cursor indicator, as you can see in the next picture:

[image]
<sub>(source: [painelflex.com.br](http://painelflex.com.br/rcfchecklist/screen.png))</sub>

If I click in a EditText, it triggers events of other EditText... it's completely insane.

Does anybody has faced to this situation before?

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is that you are not *stopping* the current event from passing the focus to the other view, you are creating *another* event to change the focus again...

Anyway, I would advise against locking a user into your EditText. If the data is incorrect, simply flag it with a bold, red font or add an error icon nearby. Don't try to hijack the focus or cursor, it creates a poor user experience.

Comment: Yes, this make sense. I will advise and block only on form submit. Anyway I think this would works. Thanks!